# Sending data from javascript to Controller Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I'm trying to send an array to an action from a controller in Yii but I'm getting 404 all the time. This is how I'm sending the data from javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + '/user/validateUser',
    data: $('#usr').val(),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res)
    {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

In my UserController i have the following action:

```
public function actionValidateUser() {
    if ($_POST > 0){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        var_dump($username);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this response:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/myapp/user/validateUser
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

What am I doing wrong? In Zend I did this and it worked just fine. Here ... I don't know.

Comment: Please, post your config with `UrlManager` settings. You get 404 when You open `http://localhost/myapp/user/validateUser`? Also You can try to use relative path `/user/validateUser` instead `baseUrl + '/user/validateUser'`

Comment: @jonijones I realized that none of the urls are working, on my local machine.

Comment: 'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
   'showScriptName'=>false,
   'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
   ),
  ),

Comment: Do you have your rewrite rules correctly set up in your .htaccess? What do you get if you open `http://localhost/myapp/index.php?r=user/validateUser` in the browser? If you get a 200 OK response there is something wrong with your .htaccess rewrite. BTW you should not do a `if ($_POST > 0)`. Better would be `if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST))` if you want to check for an existing POST array.

Comment: @chris--- hahaha, it worked how you said. but i don't know how to rewrite it. That's a problem, too.

Comment: these are my RewriteConds 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: @Matei Ok posted an answer below with instructions. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your apache rewrite rules are not correct/present.
Create/edit the file named `.htaccess` under your `htdocs` folder. Put the following in it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Save it and restart apache.
Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in your apaches httpd.conf.

Comment: sorry, but still not working. I edited the local .htaccess file, from `myapp` but still not working. It looks like yours. p.s.: I'm using Debian with Apache, not xampp.

Comment: Weird. Check your apache config that mod_rewrite is enabled under your modules section in the apaches httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

your ajax call receive a string as data, and there is not information about which field this string represent. You should indicate which field this data represents.

Try the code below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + '/user/validateUser',
    data: { username: $('#usr').val() },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res)
    {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

your original request is generating some call to //localhost/myapp/user/validateUser?<*username*>. but the code above will generating a call to //localhost/myapp/user/validateUser?username=<*username*>

Comment: still not working. i guess it's a config error. none of my actions are working on my local machine, on the servers are all good.